# How to stream events to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to add events to BigQuery in order to view them with graph using services like [ModeAnalytics](https://modeanalytics.com).

I'm not sure to grasp the full concept of BigQuery and maybe I'm making wrong assumptions about it, but what I'd like to use it for is have a (kind of) table "events" and add events to it based on the event name.

This could be like "new account", "user search", etc.

But all the documentation I could find was about loading a lot of data from other tables, a csv, a json file, etc.

I was not able to find a documentation about just doing something like a POST request with data to add to the "event" table.

How can I do ?

Comment: bigquery is not part of appengine. just use bq streaming inserts. seems you havent read or understood the basics of bigquery yet so do the required reading.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [cloud pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/overview) .  I would create a very simple cloud [data flow component](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) which will be hosted in streaming mode and will write ["streaming inserts"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) into BQ for each PubSub event raised by GAE. So basically GAE will raise events, dataflow will subscribe and read from PubSub and write to BQ.

As mentioned in the discussions below: you could also write event logs in task queue and dequeue them in a handler and then stream them straight to BQ. I generally avoid this for heavy production use as in my experience this technique generally creates "long lasting" extra instances (hence extra instance hours),especially if you have many events to write, however **it is an easy way and avoids dataflow and pubsub usage** and keeps every thing contained to appengine.

Comment: why not directly using BQ streaming insert? seems simpler if insert is what needed

Comment: Only because  pubsub makes things more durable, so if an insert fails on BQ part(which they do at times), you dont write code to handle it, pubsub retries again.

Comment: Other reason could be speed and latency. PubSub writes are async and blazing fast.

Comment: why do you mention dataflow?

Comment: App Engine task queues will also give durability, if that's where the data is coming from.

Comment: Appengine task queues will no-doubt work but I always found it strange to pay instance hours for each event raised, especially if you have millions of it. "Many ways to bell a cat" I suppose.

Comment: @Zig Mandel only because you cant directly susbscribe to pubsub message in BQ from what I know and I am conceptually against using appengine for subscription related work. Its only an advise really.

Comment: @ZigMandel fine, you are free to suggest your own version.Handling PubSub subscription in appengine or a compute engine is even worse, never to be advised for production environment unless you are happy with paying loads of instance hours. Try doing it own your own before you make judgements on suggestions..

Comment: i have done it. op simply isnt aware of streaming inserts.

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same thing. Read what I wrote again. Where did you stream inserts from ?

Comment: appengine task queue of course. not sure about your point about instance hours. how can that possibly cost less than your extra dataflow and its 10minute minimum billing per job.

Comment: For each event , you will want to enqueue it ,which will then dequeue via http request to your gae handler which in-turn will then stream insert data to BQ, where as you can make an API call to PubSub which which will then go to Dataflow (outside your GAE), DF will   batch  requests and write it straight to BQ (in auto optimised way). When this is done for few 1000 requests there is very little difference, but try doing this for a million inserts and you will see what I mean with frontend instance charges vs cost of running a dataflow.

Comment: of course at some point with super-high inserts per second you could add dataflow and batch with windowing. but that is overkill and will cost much more (or have huge delays) when the rate is not super high.

Comment: edit: i deleted my " its a very bad idea" comment as s.o. dissallows editing it. its not a bad idea only if you expect such high-rate inserts. I have used dataflow for the high-rate case and precisely had the issue that I would not scale well downwards to small activity because of dataflow minimum costs or delays from windowing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reading up on BigQuery a little more. You don't seem to have fully grasped the concept of what it actually is yet. Try [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) for starters. Think "massively scalable data analytics using SQL using the power of Google's infrastructure". After that, then have a look at its [streaming API functionality](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). This allows you to inserts "events" using http POST requests via its RESTful API.

Once you get your head around that, then there are a few solutions to stream the data in. You could go to BigQuery directly, but that's not a great idea - for obvious reasons. As mentioned in varun's answer you could indeed hook up Pub/Sub & Dataflow, but I feel that might be too much for want you need.

So, a common pattern/solution to this is to using a queue, and have something consume the events off that queue asynchronously, and push them to BigQuery in batches. This is how we do it for many of our projects and it works wonderfully.

You don't have to use GAE to achieve this. You can use any type of queue, or simply build your own custom one. For example, we run some of our queues on AWS using SQS (our events originate from Apache nodes running on EC2), and have a application which then consumes the events off SQS asynchronously.

We also use Redis to achieve the same effect. And this runs in production, is scalable, and processes about 50K events to BigQuery a minute for us. One of our engineers wrote a blog post about it [here](https://blog.shinetech.com/2014/12/19/license-to-queue/).

So, as you can see, there are many ways to build a solution to this. However, the basic premise is to have some sort of queue that processes your "events" asynchronously, and pushes them in batches to BigQuery where you can then do your analysis and plug in a BI tool to make nice graphs. Also, what solution you choose depends on your specific use case e.g. where are your events originating from? What are your skill sets like? etc.

Hope this helps.