# Querying data in "real time" from GA with BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm interesting in run some queries at BigQuery to export data in "real time", but I don't know how to do it.

The "intraday" dataset only uploads 4 or 5 times per day, and this isn't what I need.

My question: is it possible to get this data?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is necessary to visualize data with 5 min. delay at BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200721/what-is-necessary-to-visualize-data-with-5-min-delay-at-bigquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real time data you could try using the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) (I tend to use the [Python Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/analytics/v3) to run this type of analyzes).

If this does not suit your needs well then the only option I know is having some backend infra-structure that collects data from your website and publishes it to a queue, where you can further process the data.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964031/how-to-stream-events-to-bigquery/38023846#38023846) has lots of good advices, you can also check on it (such as using pub/sub, dataflow, BQ live stream and so on). Keep in mind though that this last approach is way more complex and resource dependent so it's important for you to know well what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @Will, thanks for the help. One more question, what I need if used the Python Client? Have you any manual for how to connect and Stream real data?

Comment: What you mean by connect and stream real data? You want to stream datam from the api to somewhere else? Not sure if this will help you but GA has some documentation on this subject: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/